# QT: QFileInfo().exists() doesnt work

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a network folder, mountet in /mnt/test. Now I would like to know, if the folder is available. I tried to check, if the folder 'tmp' exists.

This doesnt work for me. To check, if the folder is online, the function is called every 1-2 second.

```
if(QFileInfo(path + "tmp/").exists()) 
     test = dir.entryList();
else
     // device is not available
```

But every time, the programm tries to read the entryList().

Comment: try using QDir exists

Comment: I already tried this. But this also doesnt work. :/

Comment: It seems, that I have a timing problem. If I call the function not so quick, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there's nothing technically wrong with what you're doing, the method was never designed to be used in a polling scenario - `QFileSystemWatcher` is though.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. QFileSystemWatcher uses iNode and my network folder is a SD-Card. To change the function-call-time works for me. So I marked your answer as "solved"..